# Is Firebase sign out possible from html page of an android app?

Tags: android, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

Using Firebase auth, when the user is Authenticated, they are taken to `htmlPages` activity, where I load Url from `android_asset` in a WebView. I have two html pages. `index.html` and `profile.html`. Is there any way to show to the authenticated user profile in the `profile.html` page and Set a `Sign Out` button on that html page?

**The workflow would be like:**

1. From `SignIn` activity, after successful authentication, `htmlPages` activity starts.
2. `htmlPages` activity opens `profile.html` page inside its WebView component.
3. In the `profile.html` page, there is a `Sign Out` button and a field that show the email address of the signed in user.
4. When clicked in the `Sign Out` button of the `profile.html` page, the user is signed out, `htmlPages` activity finishes and `SignIn` activity starts.

I'm really curious that is there any way to implement such functionality in an html page.

Suppose this is my `htmlPages` activity:

```
public class htmlPages extends Activity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener {

    private AdvancedWebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.html_pages);
        mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setListener(this, this);
        mWebView.setGeolocationEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setMixedContentAllowed(true);
        mWebView.setCookiesEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setThirdPartyCookiesEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/home.html");
    }
}
```

And this is my `profile.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <title>Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
   Your email address is: <!-- User email address-->
   <button type="button">Sign Out</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think No way! You are only sending message to the `profile.html` Your firebase is not yet connected to the webpage, Unless you want to use web authentication for the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can do it, it's pretty simple we have to write our own javascript interface for web view as below and put it under the activity class which contains web view

```
inner class JSInterface(context: Context) {
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun performLogoutButtonClick() {
        Log.d("SSB Log", "Logout button clicked")
        // Perform logout action here
    }
}
```

Then we have add properties to web view as below and load the html page

```
fun loadWebViewWithButtonClick() {
    val htmlString = "<html><body><button type=\"button\", onClick=\"JSInterface.performLogoutButtonClick()\">Logout</button></body></html>"
    wvTest.apply {
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        addJavascriptInterface(JSInterface(context), "JSInterface")
        loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8")
    }
}
```

Here I'm loading html string which has logout button and I'm calling performLogoutButtonClick() of our javascript interface (The code which is inside your activity so you can easily logout user from firebase)

So, the `htmlPages` activity will be:

```
public class htmlPages extends Activity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener {

private AdvancedWebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.html_pages);
    mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setListener(this, this);
    mWebView.setGeolocationEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setMixedContentAllowed(true);
    mWebView.setCookiesEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setThirdPartyCookiesEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/profile.html");
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(this), "JSInterface");
}

private class JSInterface {
    JSInterface(Context context) {

    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void performLogoutButtonClick() {
        Log.d("SSB Log", "Logout button clicked");
    }
}
```

}

And the `profile.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
   <title>Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
   Your email address is: <!-- User email address--> 
   <button type="button", onClick="JSInterface.performLogoutButtonClick()">Sign Out</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! It seems promising. Thank you very much for the effort. Can you please explain or update the answer based on how I should implement it in the given `htmlPages` activity and `profile.html` in the update of my question?

Comment: You just have to add onClick="JSInterface.performLogoutButtonClick()" in your sign out button of profile.html like this and you are good to go

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
   Your email address is: <!-- User email address-->
<button type="button", onClick="JSInterface.performLogoutButtonClick()">Sign Out</button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Can you please have a look at the update of your answer whether I got it right or not?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't log out. I did this private class JSInterface {
        JSInterface(Context context) {

        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void performLogoutButtonClick() {
            Log.d("SSB Log", "Logout button clicked");
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }

Comment: It says `JSInterface is not defined`.

Comment: Have you wrote this 2 line in your onCreate( ) method ?

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(this), "JSInterface");

Comment: Wow! My bad. This is perfectly working. Thanks a ton. Just wondering wheather it is possible to disply the email address in the `Your email address is:` or not. Rest of it works like a charm.

Comment: Yes you can do that you have to use postUrl( ) method and pass email as a post param and use it in your html file instead of loadUrl( ), for more information reference this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#postUrl(java.lang.String,%20byte[]), hope I answered your question :)